# "AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher"

Tags: wcf, soap, vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to extend a classic ASP site by connecting to some WCF web services using SOAP 1.2 messages. So on the client end, there is no binding I am just using XMLHTTP.

I am getting the dreaded "The message with To '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher."  error.

My client is using a self-signed SSL cert, and the service end has an SSL cert set up as well.

Most of the solutions to this problem involve ServiceBehavior config on the client to turn off the Address Filter but that's not applicable in this case. Any help?

**Code**

I created a class in VBScript

```
Class SOAPRequest 
    Private objXMLHttp, webServiceURL, contentType
    Public servicePath, XmlNS, action, SOAPRequest, SOAPResponse 

    Private Sub Class_Initialize 
        set objXMLHttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        webServiceURL =  Application("Web Service URL")
        contentType =    "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8" 
    End Sub 

    Public Function SendRequest 
        'Open HTTP connection  
        objXMLHttp.Open "POST", webServiceURL & "/wcf/" & servicePath, False 

        'Setting request headers  
        objXMLHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", contentType 
        objXMLHttp.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", webServiceURL & "/wcf/" & servicePath & "?wsdl"

        dim SOAPEnvelopeStart, SOAPEnvelopeEnd
        SOAPEnvelopeStart = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' xmlns:urn='" & XmlNS & "'><soap:Header/><soap:Body>"
        SOAPEnvelopeEnd = "</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"            

        'Send SOAP request 
        objXMLHttp.Send SOAPEnvelopeStart & SOAPRequest & SOAPEnvelopeEnd

        'Get XML Response 
        SOAPResponse = objXMLHttp.ResponseText 
    End Function 

    Public Function Close 
        Set objXMLHttp = Nothing 
    End Function 
End Class
```

and then I call it as such

```
set objSOAP = New SOAPRequest

'set up the request
with objSOAP
    .servicePath    = "myservice.svc"       
    .XmlNS          = "urn:MyNamespace"
    .action         = "Action"
    .SOAPRequest    = "<urn:GetMyData></urn:GetMyData>"
end with

objSOAP.SendRequest
```

Comment: My recommendation would be to write a .NET client to call the service, then make that client COM-visible. The classic ASP can simply call a COM object and be happy. And you won't have to build XML by hand.

Comment: @John Thanks I see what you did there. :) I can even auto generate those .NET clients I suppose.

Comment: Yes, you may be able to auto-generate them. The attributes necessary for COM visibility could possibly be placed in a partial class in another class part.