# COM-visible wrapper for WCF client to VBScript

Tags: wcf, vbscript

Trying to follow the recommendation here on [my earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670957/addressfilter-mismatch-at-the-endpointdispatcher#comment30954662_20670957) about exposing a WCF service (that I did not create) to VBScript. I am getting the old "ActiveX component can't create object" when trying to CreateObject on the resulting assembly. Can anyone shed some light?

1. Generated a client using svcutil against the wsdl
2. Added the code page into a new Class Library project
3. Created a new class in the project that uses the inherited objects
4. Made just that new class ComVisible
5. Registered the resulting DLL using regasm
6. Tried a CreateObject on the resulting progid. I am getting a VBScript runtime error "Error #429 - ActiveX component can't create object."

Am I completely off base? Do I have to actually implement the interfaces from the auto generated client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem was (seems to be a common thing) using the correct version (32-bit) of Regasm. That seems to have fixed the initial problem.